# Libgdx SpriteBatch.SetProjectionMatrix makes spritebatch not draw

Tags: java, android, libgdx

`SpriteBatch.SetProjectionMatrix(cam.combined)` makes Spritebatch not draw blocks and my character but camera movement works, but if I don't use this line of code everything is drawn but camera is not working?  Does anyone know the solution, because if simply can't see it.

EDIT: sorry for the messy first post

Here is the piece of code that is troublesome:

```
public void render()
    {


        cam.update();
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);



        spriteBatch.begin();

        drawBlocks();
        drawBob();


        spriteBatch.end();
        cam.position.x = world.bob.GetPosition().x;
        cam.update();

        drawCollisionBlocks();


        if(debug)
            drawDebug();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ado!  This is a really long piece of code for SO.  Is it all really necessary for answering your question?  It will be much easier for people to help if you can narrow down the problem more than this.  (Also, when you insert code use the ` character to surround it or highlight it all and press ctrl+K rather than using `>`, which indicates a quotation.  I've fixed this in your current post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution but for anyone who may have this kind of problem in the future, the problem was in drawing methods where i was drawing 
textures like this:

CODE:

```
 spriteBatch.draw(bobFrame, bob.GetPosition().x * PPuX, bob.GetPosition().y*PPuY ,Bob.SIZE*PPuX , Bob.SIZE*PPuY );
```

PPuX,PPuY were of type int and were used for different screen sizes and that was messing spriteBatch up when i was setting the projection matrix

Comment: Thanks for posting the problem statement!  Could you enhance your answer by adding the code that *fixing* the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined)` lets spriteBatch use the coordinate system  that specified by `cam` instead of the default ones. This is because the both's coordinate system are different and the `cam.combined` will do the maths for you.

Comment: I understand that but my question is why does setting projection matrix of spritebatch to cam.combined make spritebatch to not draw my textures?? Because when i comment this line of code textures are drawn normaly, do you see any solution i could do??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually ARE drawing the sprites, however you are not seeing them because your camera viewports are not set(ie. you are looking at the wrong coordinate area).

Adding

```
cam.setToOrtho(false); //true to invert y axis
```

"Sets this camera to an orthographic projection using a viewport fitting the screen resolution, centered at (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2), with the y-axis pointing up or down."

[Link to JavaDOC here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html)